# Make sure whether row in a table is deleted

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function child_delete($c_no, $shift, $p_date, $dname) {
  $p_status = 0;
  $query = "DELETE  from $this->tb1_name2 WHERE c_no=? AND time_slot=? AND      p_date=? AND d_name=? AND p_status=?";
  $statement = $this->connection->mysqli_conn->prepare($query) or  die(mysqli_error($this->connection->mysqli_conn));
  $statement->bind_param("dsssd", $c_no, $shift, $p_date, $dname, $p_status) or  die(mysqli_error($this->connection->mysqli_conn));
  $result = $statement->execute() or die(mysqli_error($this->connection->mysqli_conn));

  print_r(mysqli_affected_rows($statement));
}
```

I used above code to delete row in a table and make sure weather the row is deleted.but it gives following error.

> **Warning**:  mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/NEW/patient_channel/controller/Patient_controller.php** on line **318**

Comment: You are mixinig OOP style with procedural

Comment: Urgh, enough with the `or die()` stuff. Where are you people still getting this from?

Comment: can you tell me how to slove this

Comment: http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the [fine manual](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

```
echo $this->connection->mysqli_conn->affected_rows;
```